# Change background of window in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Objective-C/Cocoa noob here. I'd like to make the window color in a little Mac app I'm making white, instead of the default light grey color. What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the AppDelegate you can simply invoke the `window` property

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [NSColor whiteColor];
```

otherwise from any point of you application you can call

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].backgroundColor = [NSColor whiteColor];
```

`keyWindow` is the currently "on top" window, which is probably the only one if the application is simple. For more complicated scenarios where you need a different window you can use

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] windows]
```

which will return an array of all the windows owned by the application.

Answer (score 1):

In AppDelegate.m you can change the window color by just adding the line :

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [NSColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: @Catfish_Man: I have just put the general way to change the window color in objective C in AppDelegate.m . can you suggest exact way that we can use instead of UIColor in mac app?

Comment: `self.window` is not available while using storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

In your interface builder in window attributes enable textured now you set whole window with your own color.
  then you can set your window color

```
[self.window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
-(void) awakeFromNib
{
    NSColor *red = [NSColor redColor];
    self.view.window.backgroundColor = red;
}
```